# Read a tsv file and change the first column

Tags: r

I have the following file and I am interested only on the 1st and last columns (14):

```
sp0000001-mRNA-1    f0651baa110098a342ff92218202e4d0    1016    Pfam    PF00226 DnaJ domain 76  137 7.5E-18 T   02-05-2017  IPR001623   DnaJ domain
sp0000001-mRNA-1    f0651baa110098a342ff92218202e4d0    1016    Pfam    PF05266 Protein of unknown function (DUF724)    832 1015    3.8E-41 T   02-05-2017  IPR007930   Protein of unknown function DUF724
sp0000001-mRNA-1    f0651baa110098a342ff92218202e4d0    1016    Pfam    PF11926 Domain of unknown function (DUF3444)    419 607 2.6E-56 T   02-05-2017  IPR024593   Domain of unknown function DUF3444
sp0000005-mRNA-1    8db7c080b2bc76bf090fec8662fcae20    243 Pfam    PF01472 PUA domain  155 232 1.3E-19 T   02-05-2017  IPR002478   PUA domain  GO:0003723
sp0000006-mRNA-1    edf5c2bb6341fe44b3da447099a5b2df    282 Pfam    PF03083 Sugar efflux transporter for intercellular exchange 198 261 1.4E-15 T   02-05-2017  IPR004316   SWEET sugar transporter GO:0016021
sp0000006-mRNA-1    edf5c2bb6341fe44b3da447099a5b2df    282 Pfam    PF03083 Sugar efflux transporter for intercellular exchange 7   91  1.1E-25 T   02-05-2017  IPR004316   SWEET sugar transporter GO:0016021
sp0000006-mRNA-2    edf5c2bb6341fe44b3da447099a5b2df    282 Pfam    PF03083 Sugar efflux transporter for intercellular exchange 198 261 1.4E-15 T   02-05-2017  IPR004316   SWEET sugar transporter GO:0016021
sp0000006-mRNA-2    edf5c2bb6341fe44b3da447099a5b2df    282 Pfam    PF03083 Sugar efflux transporter for intercellular exchange 7   91  1.1E-25 T   02-05-2017  IPR004316   SWEET sugar transporter GO:0016021
sp0000006-mRNA-3    51ff56e496d48682f7af1b2478190834    235 Pfam    PF03083 Sugar efflux transporter for intercellular exchange 130 214 9.6E-24 T   02-05-2017  IPR004316   SWEET sugar transporter GO:0016021
sp0000006-mRNA-3    51ff56e496d48682f7af1b2478190834    235 Pfam    PF03083 Sugar efflux transporter for intercellular exchange 7   91  7.5E-26 T   02-05-2017  IPR004316   SWEET sugar transporter GO:0016021
sp0000007-mRNA-1    ed1eda6e176feb124dbef8934b633df0    553 Pfam    PF03106 WRKY DNA -binding domain    281 338 2.6E-26 T   02-05-2017  IPR003657   WRKY domain GO:0003700|GO:0006355|GO:0043565
```

as result I try to get the following file:

```
sp0000001,n/a
sp0000005,GO:0003723
sp0000006,GO:0016021
sp0000007,GO:0003700
sp0000007,GO:0006355
sp0000007,GO:0043565
```

I tried to read the input file in the following way

```
> interproscan <- read.csv(file="ed.tsv", sep = "\t")[1,14]
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

What would be the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide reproducible input text, at the moment your pasted data is space separated, not tab.

Comment: The file is now tab separated.

Comment: Try fread from data.table: `myData <- data.table::fread("myFile.txt", select = c(1, 14), fill = TRUE)`

Comment: fread seems to work.

Comment: If we want to avoid *data.table* package, try this: `myData <- read.table("myFile.txt", sep = "\t", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)[ c(1, 14) ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like duplicate row names. I tried to save your tsv file but it's not saved as tab-separated file to me.

Anyway try this. NULL the row names:

```
> interproscan <- read.csv(file="ed.tsv", sep = "\t", row.names=NULL)[c(1,14)]
```

Comment: The file is now tab separated.

Comment: Thanks user977828. Also would like to know why I am downvoted.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how this happened.

Comment: row.names=NULL has helped

Comment: Example file is TSV, not csv, why use `read.csv`? Output should be 11 rows, by using `read.csv` we are saying the first row is a header.

Comment: @zx8754 tsv is tab separated values. Specifying `sep="\t"` for tsv is like specifying `sep=","` for csv. You can specify `header=TRUE` or `FALSE` from read.csv if you want the first column to be read as header or not. Anyway `read.csv` works (your `read.table` method works too btw :) ), what's the concern here?

Comment: @user977828 please help mark my answer if you feel it is correct or it has helped you :)